# How to make variables work in Single Quotes properly?

Tags: php, file-io, quotes

I want those variables to be filled with their values, but in config.php file its writing the variable name itself, I want like $host convert to 'localhost' with single quotes in the config.php file.

```
    $handle = fopen('../config.php', 'w');
    fwrite($handle, '
    <?php
    $connection = mysql_connect({$host}, {$user}, {$pass});
    ?>
    ');
    fclose($handle);
```

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Its just a project for my institute, I didn't learn mysqli or pdo yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use variables within single quotes, they will be represented as strings instead of variables.

You can also do it like this:

```
// Get from $_SESSION (if started)
$host = $_SESSION['host'];
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$pass = $_SESSION['pass'];

$handle = fopen('../config.php', 'w');

// try with the {}
$content = '<?php $connection = mysql_connect('."{$host},"."{$user},"."{$pass});".'?>';

// or you can try this too, but comment out the other one:
$content = '<?php $connection = mysql_connect('."\"$host\","."\"$user\","."\"$pass\");".'?>';

fwrite($handle, $content);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: It is not showing the values of $host, $user, $pass. Its giving me mysql_connect(,,); and the rest of code works fine.

Comment: Have you defined the values of $host, $user, and $pass?

Maybe they are empty variables.

@harsimarriar96

Comment: There are some values which I get from session.

Comment: try to print the $_SESSION variable using `print_r()` and find the indexes used for the values of 'host', 'user', and 'pass'.

Comment: This worked, I was missing session_start(); But there is still a problem, The values in config.php are not in '' single quotes.

Comment: You can add double-quotation marks using the backslash + mark:

`\"`

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Single quotes [do not interpolate variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single). It the major thing that distinguishes them from double quotes. Use double quotes (or something else, such as [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf)) instead.

Comment: I want to write the config.php file can you help me how can I write it? with the variables printing.

Comment: @harsimarriar96 Quentin has answered you're question, you're on the right lines so go and have a go at doing it yourself. If you have any further questions: create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you use double quotes it works:

```
$handle = fopen('../config.php', 'w');
fwrite($handle, "
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect({$host}, {$user}, {$pass});
?>
");
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: When I try to double quotes, It reads the $connection variable too, I want it to read only $host, $user, $pass and the rest should be written as it is.

Comment: Put a \ in front of $connection to escape it to avoid php reading it as a variable.